# Unexpected margin/space between 2 divs

Tags: html, css, margin, jsfiddle

i have a unexpected space between the `<section>` and `<aside>` tags as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/drymisty/ujj0fjqo/ 
I don't know why that's happening with the  and  tags but not with `<div id="logo">` and `<nav>` tags.
The space is also selectionable like text.
I tried to fix it adding `float: left;` to the `<section>` and it works but float is very old.

Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you made your section elements inline, they're sensitive to white space in the code. Simple remove it `</section><aside>` or `</section><!--    --><aside>`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zsxLn586/)**